# Integration Identity Framework with custom Db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to achieve a solution where I can add additional userdata to another table then the AspNetUser (identity framework). One time the user registers and logs in, I only want to retrieve data from this new table. So I am making a one to one relation to the ApplicationUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //[ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

And I have 2 Db Context

```
public class MainDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectType> ProjectTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MainDbContext()
        :base("MainDb")
    {

    }
}
```

And this one is my Context of the Identity Framework.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("MainDb", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two databases? Can't you make your `MainDbContext` inherit `IdentityDbContext`? As far as I know you can't make objects of a DbContext have navigation property to objects which is not in the same context.

Comment: I have only one database, but two context. How can i make it work, i need to add custom tables to the db, that will work with the identity framework. Could you explain the how i can make it inherit, so the when the db creates the identity framework tables, that it also creates my custom table.

Comment: Like you did to `ApplicationDbContext `, I'm gonna answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use two `DbContext`'s at all. You can make your main DbContext inherit `IdentityDbContext`, like this:

```
public class MainDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectType> ProjectTypes { get; set; }

    public MainDbContext()
        :base("MainDb")
    {

    }
}
```

You also don't have to create a separate class for custom properties (unless you really wanted this). You could do like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Two things to take note here:

- You don't need an Id column for User, because `IdentityUser` parent class already declares it.
- You don't need to put a DbSet for you User, since `IdentityDbContext` already declares it.

This is the simplest scenario. It is possible to create a separate class for custom properties, and also separated `DbContexts`, but this is for complex scenarios, I think you should start/keep things the simplest you can.